# How to retrieve a number from a url in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have this url in my lambda_handler

```
        myUrl = http://www.tester.com/changePattern/7676
```

I want to extract the number 7676. This can be any number before the /

How can I achieve this using python?

The number extracted will be passed to other function.

Comment: Try this: `myUrl = 'http://www.tester.com/changePattern/7676';
number = myUrl.split('/')[-1]`

Comment: This is the result after running the code above ['http:', '', 'www.tester.com', 'changePattern', '7676']

Comment: Did you include the `[-1]` at the end? The result you showed is the list returned by the `split()` method of `str` datatype. Using `[-1]` gives you the final element of that list, or `7676`.

Comment: I forgot to include it but now included it. It works.